# Is it possible to pass Flux to the body of webClient POST?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have an endpoint like this :

```
@PostMapping("/products")
Flux<Product> getProducts(@RequestBody Flux<String> ids) {
    return Flux...
}
```

On my client side, I want to consume this endpoint but not sure how to pass a Flux of String in the body (I don't want to make it a list)

```
Flux<Product> getProducts(Flux<String> ids) {
  return webClient.post().uri("/products")
      .body(/* .. how should I do here? ..*/)
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToFlux(Product.class);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can, in fact, pass in a Flux into the `.body()` method on the `WebClient`

```
Flux<Person> personFlux = ... ;

Mono<Void> result = client.post()
        .uri("/persons/{id}", id)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
        .body(personFlux, Person.class)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Void.class);
```

Example taken from [Spring Reference Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-body)

The variation of the `body()` method you'd want to use is:

```
<T,P extends org.reactivestreams.Publisher<T>> WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> body(P publisher,
                                                                                    Class<T> elementClass)
```

Relevant [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestBodySpec.html#body-P-java.lang.Class-) for this method

Comment: Thanks. Should the body be annotated with @RequestBody in the server method or something else?